# Asp.net mvc 2 issue with saving edited form values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, object, edit

I am having a problem being able to edit a column in a table, even though I can add and delete them quite easily. I ahve done this sort of thing before and had no problems with it, so I am stumped to as why it is happening now.

I can click on a players name and get his details up, but when I edit the players details in the view and click save, its saying the Sequence contains no elements.

Can someone please help me rectify this problem as it is driving me crazy, it would be much appreciated as it is most likely a simple solution.

Here is my code:

Repository:

```
public Players PlayersDetails(String Name)
{
    var players = (from p in _entities.Players      
                where p.FullName == Name
                select p).First();
    return players;
}

public void playersEdit(Players playersToEdit)
{
    var originalPlayer = PlayersDetails(playersToEdit.FullName);
    _entities.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalPlayer.EntityKey.EntitySetName, playersToEdit);
    _entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

IRepository:

```
public interface IHuddRLRepository
{
    //Player List
    IEnumerable<Players> PlayersList();
    Players PlayersDetails(String Name);
    void playersCreate(Players playersToCreate);
    void playersEdit(Players playersToEdit);
    void playersDelete(Players playersToDelete);
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(String FullName)
{
    Players players = _entities.PlayerDetails(FullName);
    return View(players);
}

[ValidateInput(false)]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Players playersToEdit)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        _entities.playersEdit(playersToEdit);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Players");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking for player by name? Are you sure that name you get in controller is correct?

Comment: because its going to be a website for a local university sports team which will be having player profiles, where admin can log in and then add, edit or delete a profile if needed to.

Comment: That's not the question. I asked why do you use *name* for lookup, and not *id*.

Comment: oh sorry, lost the plot for a second there. I deciced to not have an id on the player, since its not that important within the site. is that the problem?

Comment: What happens if admin decides to change typo in player name?

Comment: well thats what the problem is, ive just realised that I can fully edit other information about the player but not the name. would it be best to have an id, therefore making that the primary key instead of the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequence contains no elements means that the query didn't return a result when you were expecting one (using First() instead of FirstOrDefault() which returns null when no elements are found). I'm guessing that since you try to do a lookup using the edited player data, you must have changed the player's name, which wouldn't exist in the database yet.

What you should be doing is using an ID for the player lookup since that wouldn't be editable and would refer to the data you are trying to edit.

Comment: yes I was trying to change the players name, which like you say is the problem. I will do this via the ID instead therefore making me able to change the player name instead